# Extract restricted regression coefficients without using tidy

Tags: r, dplyr, regression, lm, panel-data

I'm using the restriktor package to perform restricted regressions; however, at the same time I'm doing the restricted regressions by group using the dplyr. In order to extract the coefficients and have them formatted into a nice panel format, I use tidy and broom but the tidy packaged doesn't work on the restriktor so I'm not sure how to go about extracting the coefficients:

```
library(restriktor)
library(dplyr)
reg = 
  mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  do(model = restriktor(lm(mpg ~ wt + hp, data =.), constraints = ' wt  < -4 '))
```

I would like to have the b.restr which is the restricted model coefficients to be extracted for each group and formatted together into a panel normally I would use the following:

```
reg = 
  mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  do({model = restriktor(lm(mpg ~ wt + hp, data =.), constraints = ' wt  < -4 ')    # create your model
  data.frame(tidy(model),              # get coefficient info
             glance(model))})
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error: No tidy method for objects of class restriktor
```

All I want is to extract the following elements from the lists and put them altogether with their  group identifier in one panel format:

```
reg[[2]][[1]][["b.restr"]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group_modify` (which is preferred over `do` now) with `coef`/`as.list`/`as_tibble`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(restriktor)

# coefficients and R2's or NAs if too few rows for restriktor
co <- function(fo, data) {
   fm <- lm(fo, data)
   coef_lm <- coef(fm)
   min_rows <- length(coef_lm)
   if (nrow(data) <= min_rows) NA * c(coef_lm, R2.org = NA, R2.reduced = NA)
   else {
    r <- restriktor(fm, constraints = ' wt  < -4 ')
    c(coef(r), R2.org = r$R2.org, R2.reduced = r$R2.reduced)
   }
}


mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  group_modify(~ {
    .x %>%
      co(mpg ~ wt + hp, .) %>%
      as.list %>%
      as_tibble
  }) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
 tibble: 3 x 6
    cyl `(Intercept)`    wt      hp R2.org R2.reduced
  <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl>
1     4          45.8 -5.12 -0.0905  0.681      0.681
2     6          35.3 -4    -0.0256  0.589      0.667
3     8          33.9 -4    -0.0132  0.497      0.652
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. It works perfectly on the sample data; however, when I try to implement it on my much larger dataset with two grouping variables I get the following error: Error in if (all(Amat == 0)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
Please note that I have already removed all the NA, NULL and infinite values from the whole dataset.  I'm not sure what this error even refers to

Comment: You may have some groups that have too few rows.  I have changed it so that it produces NA's for any group with less than `min_rows` rows.  Increase that if even that is not enough.

Comment: Thank a lot. I just put a min 100 obs for each regression and now I'm not getting any errors. Thank you so much. I've been stuck on this problem for 2 weeks now until I found the recently made restriktor pacakge. This literally saved me!

Comment: Hi, one more quick question? what would be the process like if I would also like to extract the R^2 and p-value?

Comment: Have added R2.  You can look through `str(r)` and grab anything else there that you want.

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems like in order to get the standard error, t-value and p_value  you need to run the summary for each restriktor regression. However, I don't seem to be able to do summary by group even though it works if I only apply it to the one cyl at a time. Anyway to apply summary or get the p-value foe each coefficient? It's not in the standard part of the restriktor function.

Comment: `co` is run on each group separately so anything you add to it will be specific to that group.

Comment: Yeah I understand! the problem is I can't fit the summary output into a dataframe. Are there any other way to get the p-value that comes from that? I get the following error: Error in as.data.frame.default(r) : 
cannot coerce class ‘c("summary.restriktor", "summary.conLM")’ to a data.frame

Comment: `str(summary(r))` shows what you can grab from `summary`.  There are also other functions in the restriktor package that you can use to get various quantities.   Try `methods(class = "restriktor")` and then use `str` to look through the output of those.

Comment: So I would like to call the coefficients within the summary nested list and I run the following:  co <- function(fo, data) {
  fm <- lm(fo, data)
  coef_lm <- coef(fm)
  min_rows <- length(coef_lm)
  if (nrow(data) <= min_rows) NA * c(coef_lm, R2.org = NA, R2.reduced = NA)
  else {
    r <- summary(restriktor(fm, constraints = ' wt  < -4 '))
    c(as.data.frame(r["coefficients"]))
  }
}
this works but unfortunately, the row names are missing so I can't tell the names of the regressors, intercept etc. Anyway to keep the rownames when extracting an element from the summary?